# How do the Sho dll's from Microsoft Research compare to the open-source Math.NET numerics project

Tags: .net, machine-learning, data-mining, linear-algebra, numerical

I'm considering Sho from the perspective of developing general .NET applications and something that has been difficult for me in the past is that there is NO standard math library for the .NET platform. Aside from the commercial implementations, two current .NET libraries stand-out for their depth and breadth:

1) Sho (closed source?, newer but will it get the nod to be included in the core MS .NET framework)

2) Math.NET numerics (open-source, though in "beta" quite a mature project in its own right and with other guys from MSoft working on the project)

The similarities seem so many that I am left thinking that they should actually start co-operating?

I have limited my choice to the above two due to performance considerations as they both allow connections to the native fast libraries of MKL, ACML, LAPACK etc...

Is anyone else looking into something similar?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen these 2 projects provide very different features. Math.Net is a numerical library with standard features.

The Sho project seems to aim at something closer to matlab with a kind of an interactive scripting shell. Also it depends what you want to do with it, but currently it's a microsoft research project and the license doesn't allow commercial applications.

Comment: The license does say "For clarity, internal use by a commercial entity is considered a non-commercial purpose and is permitted under this Agreement."